# How to make a faded line in title to be responsive?

Tags: html, css, gradient

I have a line in title like this one
[Faded line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVp2D.png).
When title is long the line becomes shorter and the fading effect dissapears
[Faded line2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAdg5.png)
I use this css for the line in h1

```
.sub_title h1:before {
    content: "";
    width: 42%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: -43.6%;
    text-align: right;
    height: 2px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 60% 0%, 0, 239% 90%, 1090, from(#5CAECE), to(#fff));
}
.sub_title h1:after {
    content: "";
    width: 42%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: 1.5%;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 60% 0%, 0, -139% 90%, 1090, from(#5CAECE), to(#fff));
}
```

Is there anyway to make this line responsive, so that no matter how long the tilte is, the line will become shorter but will maintain the fading effect?

Comment: Is it possible to include more of the CSS and the HTML in order to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions for that, but the most secure and easiest for me would be to use flexbox, semantic is clear without any additional bloat, and works fine I think: https://jsfiddle.net/prowseed/szgeag97/

The whole magic lies in specific flexbox features:

```
.title {
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;

  &:before, &:after {
    content:'';
    flex: 2 1 90px;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 60%);
    height:4px;
  }

  &:after {
    background:linear-gradient(to left, rgba(30,87,153,0) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 60%);
  }

  h1 {
    flex:0 1 auto;
    padding:0 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me.=)

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that if you know your background color

```
`https://codepen.io/SashaZhardetskaya/pen/eEvmdQ#code-area`
```

Answer (score -1):

use `linear-gradient` instead of `-webkit-gradient`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

and I guess `background-size: cover;` and `background-repeat: no-repeat;` would help